# decoding an ASCII character message

Tags: decode, basic

I have no idea what im doing I need to decode `mmZ\dxZmx]Zpgy`, I have an example but not sure what to do please help!

```
 If (EncryptedChar - Key < 32) then

 DecryptedChar = ((EncryptedChar - Key) + 127) - 32

Else

DecryptedChar = (EncryptedChar - Key)
```

the key us unknown 1-100

Comment: I'll bet it's 88. (And I think there's a missing `:` or `Z` at the start of the message.)

Comment: Anyway, what part do you not know how to do? How to loop over the characters of a string? How to convert a character to a number and back, so you can do arithmetic like `- Key` on them? How to accumulate each `DecryptedChar` up into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord` and `chr` to convert between the ordinals (`ord`) of the ASCII value and the and the characters (`chr`) they represent.

Then you can loop through your string and apply the your algorithm to each.

For example:

```
import sys
SecretMessage = "mmZ\dxZmx]Zpgy"
Key = 88
for Letter in SecretMessage:
    EncryptedChar = ord(Letter)
    if (EncryptedChar - Key) < 32:
        DecryptedChar = ((EncryptedChar - Key) + 127) - 32
    else:
        DecryptedChar = (EncryptedChar - Key)
    sys.stdout.write(chr(DecryptedChar))
```

Run this to see the output. I'll leave the exercise of finding the key value `88` up to you (hint: it involves iterations). You also appear to be missing the first letter from `SecretMessage` (probably a `:`).